# How can I defend my JavaScript game from robbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to `defend` my js game, because as you know if we `inspect the element`, we can see the js and the html source.
I know, that I can `obfuscate` it, but if I do it, I only earn  that they can't really change the game.

So is there any way to defend, or every js game would be open source?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to prevent anything.

Comment: You seem to know the answer already.

Comment: Have business logic on the server and ajax it. Then at most they can steal your visualization and not the business logic itself.

Comment: Just because someone can read your code, that doesn't give them any IP rights over it. Unless you've specifically published it under such a license, of course

Comment: Your only protection is a legal one (and that is expensive to enforce).

Comment: That's sad :( Thanks for the answers!